# How to make intellij to omit lombok annotations

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, intellij-lombok-plugin

I am using `lombok` annotations (`@Getter`,`@Setter`). I use Auto format in Intellij (automatic after every commit). The problem is that it always stack them. So from this:

```
@Getter @Setter
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "objectName", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@OrderBy(Object.NAME)
private Set<Object> exmaple = new HashSet<>();
```

I get this:

```
@Getter 
@Setter
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "objectName", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@OrderBy(Object.NAME)
private Set<Object> exmaple = new HashSet<>();
```

If I change in `Settings`->`Editor`->`Java`->`Wrapping and braces`->`Annotation parameters` to `wrap always` by definition it wraps everything. If check `Align when multiline` nothing changes.

Is it possible to make intellij auto-format mechanism to ignore certain (f.e. lombok) annotations ? or any other way to make auto-format put them next to each other instead stack them ?

Answer (score 0):

Go **Setting** → **Editor** → **Code Style** → **Java** → **Wrapping and Braces tab** and try to change **Field annotations** to '**Do not wrap**'

Comment: I agree, thank you for that. But with more than `4` annotations It does not look nice. Are you sure that there is no way to do something else that might help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go **Setting** → **Editor** → **Code Style** → **Java** → **Wrapping
   and Braces** tab
2. Change **Field Annotations** to **'Wrap if long'**
3. Check '**Do not wrap after single annotation**'.

It works for me.